# What's the role of Javascript / jQuery / Coffeescript in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I have been learning Ruby & more specifically the rails framework the past few months and am now preparing to dive into Javascript. I know that any good/modern rails app will include javascript within its code. I also know that Javascript/Jquery/Coffescript help with adding some interactivity, style and functionality to web apps.

My question is what is the standard set of problems/features that one approaches with JS (or Jquery/Coffescript ect) vs Ruby/Rails?

Comment: JavaScript is client-side; Ruby/Rails is server-side.  If you're not fully clear on what jQuery (and other JavaScript libraries) are exactly, I recommend you read [this article](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/09/09/gain-a-better-understanding-of-jquery/) I wrote.

Comment: thanks, great article!... I get that rails is server side and JS is Client site, but what are some examples of typical actions that one would use JS for vs Rails in an app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Use Rails to:

- Build **Extensible** applications with MVC (Model, View, Controller) code.
- Manage **Data** (CRUD - Create, Read, Update, Delete).
- Manage **Security** (Access) and Authentication (Identity).
- Manage **State** over time.
- Apply **REST** for standard actions.
- Apply a 'middle layer' for **validations** (the database being the backend validator).
- Manage the back end part of  **AJAX** communication and processing.
- Build applications in a TDD/BDD **Agile** fashion with code that is easy to understand.
- Build **API's** for communication.
- Provide a full-stack **Application Server**.

> Use Javascript and libraries like jQuery for:

- Improved user **interaction** - Sliders, highlights, glows, color changes, etc.
- Improved user **feedback** - the 'front line' for immediate feedback for validations.
- Improved page load **speed** - less page loads and fewer user experience interrupts.
- Improved User **experience** with effects. - Transitions, Fades, etc.
- Presenting and Managing **interactive** contents e.g. maps, video, sounds.
- Tasks that are specific to managing the **DOM** - HTML, CSS and browser events.
- The front end part of communication via **AJAX**.
- Making things look & work **similarly** in different browsers & browser versions.
- Pre-built **tools** for sliders, image fades, forms, layouts, tool tips, etc.
- Pre-built **mini-apps**, ready to apply to any data. [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) is one amazing example!

Comment: I just wanted to add that since Rails (the back-end) gives you an MVC framework to keep your code organized, you may want to look into Javascript frameworks to organize your front-end work.  Backbone is an MVC javascript framework and KnockoutJS is an MVVM framework.  Either one will make it much easier to manage your javascript files and both can be used in conjunction with JQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Some tasks you would do with javascript:

- update parts of a web page without the user having to reload the whole page.
- 3rd party sources eg - I had google map on a site and used almost all javascript for it.
- pop-ups, user interaction
- display videos, interactive images.

Some tasks you would do with ruby/rails:

- all your server side stuff like get data from your models.
- make sense of any data your client sends to your application.
- process your data before sending it to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is client side and can manipulate the page after it has loaded. Its more about interaction with the page while rails is the backend of a app. Javascript is present in most web sites, ruby/rails or not.